# Which is the most comprehensive browser compatibility testing tool?

Tags: cross-browser, automated-tests

An ideal one would be where I could:

- Test my JS live, not just see screenshots
- Test in multiple browsers in multiple OSes
- Test under various resolutions
- Test in different mobile platforms

I know that's too much to ask for, but which one gets closest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two that spring immediately to mind are:

- http://browsershots.org/
- http://deviceanywhere.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can use Selenium RC or Selenium 2 (WebDriver) for automated cross-browser testing as well as different platform.

Selenium WebDriver is better than Selenium RC. Selenium RC is deprecated now. You can find the details about Selenium2 (WebDriver) in the following URL:

```
http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp
```